# BeautifulSoup Scraping td & tr

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the price data (high and low) from the 3rd table (corn).  The code is return "None":

```
import urllib2                          
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup           
import time                           
import re                               
start_urls = 4539                       
nb_quotes = 10                          
for urls in range (start_urls, start_urls - nb_quotes, -1):

    start_time = time.time()

    # construct the URLs strings
    url = 'http://markets.iowafarmbureau.com/markets/fixed.php?page=egrains' 

    # Read the HTML page content
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # Create a beautifulsoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    # Search the table to be parsed in the whole HTML code
    tables = soup.findAll('table')
    tab = tables[2]                 # This is the table to be parsed   

    low_tmp = str(tab.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('td')[1].getText())     #Low price
    low = re.sub('[+]', '', low_tmp)                                
    high_tmp = str(tab.findAll('tr')[0].findAll('td')[2].string)    # High price
    high = re.sub('[+]', '', high_tmp)                             


    stop_time = time.time()


    print low, '\t', high, '(%0.1f s)' % (stop_time - start_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the table is filled up on the browser side using the following javascript call:

```
document.write(getQuoteboardHTML(
    splitQuote(quotes, 'ZC*1,ZC*2,ZC*3,ZC*4,ZC*5,ZC*6,ZC*7,ZC*8,ZC*9'.split(/,/)),
    'shortmonthonly,high,low,last,change'.split(/,/), { nospacers: true }));
```

`BeautifulSoup` is an HTML parser - it would not execute javascript.

Basically, you need something to execute that javascript for you.

One solution would be to utilize a real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver


url = "http://markets.iowafarmbureau.com/markets/fixed.php?page=egrains"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(div[@class="fixedpage_heading"], "CORN")]/table[@class="homepage_quoteboard"]')
for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:
    month = row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_shortmonthonly').text
    low = row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_low').text
    high = row.find_element_by_class_name('quotefield_high').text

    print month, low, high

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
SEP 329-0 338-0
DEC 335-6 345-4
MAR 348-2 358-0
MAY 356-6 366-0
JUL 364-0 373-4
SEP 372-0 379-4
DEC 382-0 390-2
MAR 392-4 399-0
MAY 400-0 405-0
```

---

Another option would be to "go down to metal" and see what `splitQuote()` and `getQuoteboardHTML()` js function actually do. Using browser developer tools, you can see that there is an underlying request going to [this url](http://www.agricharts.com/marketdata/jsquote.php?varname=quotes&symbols=ZC*1,ZC*2,ZC*3,ZC*4,ZC*5,ZC*6,ZC*7,ZC*8,ZC*9,ZS*1,ZS*2,ZS*3,ZS*4,ZS*5,ZS*6,ZS*7,ZS*8,ZS*9,ZS*10,ZW*1,ZW*2,ZW*3,ZW*4,ZW*5,ZW*6,ZO*1,ZO*2,ZO*3,ZO*4,ZM*1,ZM*2,ZM*3,ZM*4,ZM*5,ZM*6,ZM*7,ZM*8,MW*1,MW*2,KE*1,KE*2,ZL*1,ZL*2,ZL*3,ZL*4,ZL*5,ZL*6,ZL*7,ZL*8,ZR*1,ZR*2,ZR*3,ZR*4,ZR*5&user=&pass=&display_ice=&ice_exchanges=), that returns a piece of javascript code containing all objects with the data for the tables on the page:

```
var quotes = { 'ZC*1': { name: 'Corn', flag: 's', price_2_close: '338.75', open_interest: '2701', tradetime: '20140911133000', symbol: 'ZCU14', open: '338', high: '338', low: '329', last: '331.75', change: '-7', pctchange: '-2.07', volume: '1623', exchange: 'CBOT', type: '2', unitcode: '-1', date: '14104 ... ', month: 'May 2015', shortmonth: 'May 2015' } };
```

If you manage to extract necessary parts from it - this would be your second option.

Comment: Thanks greatly!  It took a while to figure out how to properly download selenium.  Once I got selenium downloaded, I had to play around with driver (ChromeDirver).  I got it now.  I'm stoked!

Comment: For those who are having issues with chromedriver, be sure to install selenium properly, and go to: "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html" and download the latest version (see latest version).  Then make sure you put the chromedriver.exe (that you just downloaded) in the Scripts folder (e.g. Anaconda\Scripts, or Python27\Scripts); otherwise the path will be incorrect.  This worked for me after a week of playing around with it.